# adb.exe is too old; please install version 1.0.39 or later......how to update adb version

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, adb, flutter-dependencies

I will try to run my first flutter App in my samsung phone it give the following error (i will also try another phone it also same)

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A105F in debug mode...
The ADB at "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" is too old; please install version 1.0.39 or later.
Error launching application on SM A105F.
```

I am using android studio in the windows environment

how to update adb version plz help

Comment: update your android sdk tool

Comment: I did it but not work I have latest android SDK build tools 29.0.2

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same issue and I have solved this issue using the below steps. would you please refer below steps it will help you to solve the above issue

- Open Android studio then click on SDK manager it showing in right side icon then select Update and click on check now button for platform-tools
  ( Android studio -> SDK manager ->Updates ->check now )

[image: Would you please refer below screenshot]

Let me know your thought for the same
Thank you

Comment: easiest way to overwrite new version,thank u praful argiddi

Answer (score 0):

Using Command Line for update android sdk and platform ,adb..etc(credits @nsg)

```
android list sdk --all
```

And then to get one of the packages in that list from the command line, use:

android update sdk -u -a -t 
Where -u stands for --no-ui, -a stands for --all and -t stands for --filter.

If you need to install multiple packages do:

```
android update sdk -u -a -t 1,2,3,4,..,n
```